# Running my python project using the pysimplegui module on android (with pydroid3?)

Tags: android, python-3.x, pysimplegui, pydroid

i want to run my python project on an android device.
Is there a way to run it on android?
I tried with pydroid3 and the plugininstaller and got the error message:
"gui applications cannot be ran from terminal use ide to run these applications."
But when trying a simple popup window, the gui is working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Go to PySimpleGUI.org, search for "pydroid3".  Same with PySimpleGUI.com (you'll find demo programs)